# WebFlux Mono, handle http errors gracefully

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am introducing WebFlux into a micro-service and I am having issues gracefully handling http errors from the service being called.

I have a list of ids for which I need to retrieve a single entity from another rest service. If one of the ids returns a http error I dont want to throw an exception, I want to log the http error, "return null" and move on to the next id in the list.

I have attempted to use `onStatus` and have this return `Mono.empty` when an error status is recieved, however I get the following `UnsupportedMediaException`:
`Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=MyView`

My code currently stands thus:

```
        final MyView view = webClient.get()
                .uri(builder -> builder.path("someUrl").build("someId"))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> {
                    log.error("some error message");
                    return Mono.empty();
                })
                .bodyToMono(MyView.class)
                .blockOptional()
                .orElse(null);
```

Any suggestions as too what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: You are fetching a stream of items `octet-stream`. A stream of items are many items, and you are trying to stick many items into a `Mono`. A `Mono` is a single item. Try using `bodyToFlux` instead, a `Flux` is multiple items.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for the suggestion.   However that is not what is happening here, the called service only returns a single item, so a `Mono` is correct.  `octet-stream` is the content-type of the response.   I thought I was either doing something wrong or having issues with Jackson, turns out I hadnt put the correct `content-type` on the error response in my test fixture. I should have read the error properly rather than assuming that in my limited Webflux experience I had made a mistake in processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue was in the error message: `Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=MyView`.

The answer was to set the `content-type` :)